# Is it possible to use SpringData MongoDB repository to execute an arbitrary query, with pagination?

Tags: mongodb, pagination, spring-data

We have a use case where a user can pass in arbitrary search criteria for a collection, and wants the output paged.  Using Spring Data repositories, this is quite simple if we know ahead of time what attributes they may be searching on by simple extending MongoRepository, and declaring a:

`Page<Thing> findByFooAndBarAndBaz(Type foo, Type bar, Type baz, Pageable page)`

However, if we generate the query ourselves either using the fluent interface or constructing a mongo string and wrapping it in a `BasicQuery` class, I can not find a way to get that into a repository instance.  There is no:

`Page<Thing> findByQuery(Query q, Pageable page)`

functionality that I have been able to see.

Nor can I see how to hook into the `MongoTemplate` querying functionality with the Page abstraction.

I'm hoping I don't have to roll my own paging (calculating skip and limit parameters, which I guess is not hard) and call into the template directly, but I guess I can if that's the best choice.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this can be done in the way I'd hoped, but I've come up with a workaround.  As background, we put all our methods to do data access in a DAO, and some delegate to the repository, some to the template.

- Wrote a DAO method which takes our arbitrary filter string (which I have a utility that converts it to standard mongo JSON query syntax.
- Wrap that in a BasicQuery to get a "countQuery".
- Use that countQuery to get a total count of records using `MongoTemplate#count(Query, Class)`
- Append my paging criteria to create a "pageQuery" using `Query#with(Pageable)`
- Run the pageQuery with `MongoTemplate#find(Query, Pageable)`
- Get the `List<T>` result from that, the `Pageable` that was used for the query and the `count` returned from the countQuery run, and construct a new `PageImp` to return to the caller.

Basically, this (`DocDbDomain` is a test domain class for testing out document db stuff):

```
    Query countQuery = new BasicQuery(toMongoQueryString(filterString));
    Query pageQuery = countQuery.with(pageRequest);
    long total = template.count(countQuery, DocDbDomain.class);

    List<DocDbDomain> content = template.find(pageQuery, DocDbDomain.class);

    return new PageImpl<DocDbDomain>(content, pageRequest, total);
```

Comment: Looks like this is the only option to achieve this goal. After 3 years is there any other alternative introduced?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@Query` annotation to execute an arbitrary query through a repository method:

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

  @Query("{ 'firstname' : ?0 }")
  Page<Person> findByCustomQuery(String firstname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Generally speaking, `@Query` can contain any JSON query you can execute via the shell but with the `?0` kind of syntax to replace parameter values. You can find more information on the basic mechanism in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based).

Comment: hi. Is this still the only option? Because it does not fit into real cases. For instance I have detailed search query with lots of fields but these fields may or may not occur in query. So writing them into `@Query`is not an option. Mongodb does not accept null criteria more than once and also given null value for query fields changes query.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't express your query within the `@Query`-Annotation, you can use the Spring Repository `PageableExecutionUtils` for your custom queries.

For example like this:

```
@Override
public Page<XXX> findSophisticatedXXX(/* params, ... */ @NotNull Pageable pageable) {

    Query query = query(
            where("...")
            // ... sophisticated query ...
    ).with(pageable);

    List<XXX> list = mongoOperations.find(query, XXX.class);
    return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(list, pageable,
              () -> mongoOperations.count((Query.of(query).limit(-1).skip(-1), XXX.class));
}
```

Like in the original Spring Data Repository, the `PageableExecutionUtils` will do a separated `count` request and wrap it into a nice `Page` for you.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/3012bcd575d85ad7cd11e07962fc168d4bbc98b2/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/support/SimpleMongoRepository.java#L275-L285) you can see that spring is doing the same.

Comment: this will load all the results in memory, no?